# Issue running Spark on windows 10

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark

I installed Spark on windows 10 with the following guide:
https://simonsuthers.wordpress.com/2017/02/13/how-to-install-spark-on-a-windows-10-machine/

But when I try to run the Jupyter notebook with a simple code, it gives me the following error:

> NameError: name 'sc' is not defined

And also I'm getting another warning on the cmd:

> '[IPKernelApp] WARNING | Unknown error in handling PYTHONSTARTUP file
>   C:\Spark\bin..\python\pyspark\shell.py:'

But i tried to create a python function which runs fine on the Jupyter notebook.

Can someone please help to understand and fix the problem?

Answer (score 2):

I was getting the same error using the same guide. After a few attempts, I noticed Anaconda3-4.3.0 (the version listed in the guide) uses Python 3.6 which doesn't yet work with spark. I went ahead and uninstalled Anaconda3-4.3.0 and installed Anaconda3-4.2.0 which uses Python 3.5 and it fixed the error.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem with Spark 2.1 (Dez 28, 2016) and Windows 10.
When I ran Spark in the shell, I got the error:

```
The root scratch dir: /tmp/hive on HDFS should be writable. Current permissions are: rw-rw-rw-
```

But running:

```
winutils.exe chmod 777 D:\tmp\hive
```

couldn't solve the problem.

It seems that this is a Windows - Spark compatibility problem, which is solved in Spark 2.0.2 (Nov 14, 2016), but back in 2.1.0 (Dez 28). Just running the [version 2.0.2](http://spark.apache.org/downloads.html) solved my problem!

Spark 1.6.3 also works for me!

Answer (score 0):

I faced same issue in mac and resolved it by following steps:

1. Uninstall already installed Anaconda3-4.3.0 using below command:

   `rm -rf ~/anaconda3`
2. Download Anaconda3-4.2.0 from [here](https://repo.continuum.io/archive/Anaconda3-4.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh).
3. Run the above downloaded sh file to install it using cmd :

   `sh Anaconda3-4.2.0-MacOSX-x86_64.sh`
4. Add the below env variables in ~/.bash_profile:

   `export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON=jupyter
       export PYSPARK_DRIVER_PYTHON_OPTS='notebook'
       export PYSPARK_SUBMIT_ARGS="--master local[2]"`
5. Restart your terminal.

Answer (score 0):

I run into the same problem running spark on mac. Good starting point for me was running the script, that causes the error. I found that a library was missing.

```
$ python /spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/pyspark/shell.py", line 28, in <module>
    import py4j
ImportError: No module named py4j
```

Adding the library to `PYTHONPATH` fixed the issue.

```
$ export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/spark/spark-2.1.0-bin-hadoop2.7/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip
```